Homology group of an attaching space
Consider a cylinder without bottom nor top: $S^1 \times [0,1]$ and another circle $S^1$ on the complex plain. We may define a map of $f: z \rightarrow z^2$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$, which is a map of degree 2. Then we may attach $S^1 \times I$ with $S^1$ by identifying $(z,0) \sim f(z)$ and we get an attaching space $X = S^1 \times I \cap S^1/\sim$. Clearly its bottom is now $\mathbb{R}P^1$.

My question: Is this space homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^1$? If not, how to compute its homology group?

I have tried cellular homology with the following CW-complex structure: 
We may identify $A,B$ and $C,D,E$ separately and we identify segments with respect to the direction of the arrows. We get
2 0-cells. 3 1-cells and 1 2-cell.
As a result, we have the following chain complex:
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{Z}^3 \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow 0$$
According to the cellular degree formula, we may have $f(1) = (1,0,2)$, $g(1,0,0) = g(0,0,1)= 0,g(0,1,0) = 1 $. As a result, $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}_2
$ and $H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z}$. But I also think that $X$ might be homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^1 = S^1$, then the first homology group is $\mathbb{Z}$ so my argument is wrong. Can someone tell me if $X$ is indeed homotopic to $S^1$, or if my computation of homology group is correct?

$X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. The space you're considering is an instance of a more general construction that goes by the name of "mapping cyclinder"; if you look this up you should have no trouble finding a proof.

@BenSteffan, thank you for your hint!
